# Use '&' to create pointer to member error

Tags: c++, pointers

I am creating a game in c++ and I have called a function, however I am getting an error saying i need to insert an ampersand to create a pointer to a member. However, I am unsure where this needs to go...

```
string MouseAndCatGame::prepareGrid(){
    //prepare a string that holds the grid information
    ostringstream os;
    for (int row(1); row <= SIZE; ++row)    //for each row (vertically)
    {
        for (int col(1); col <= SIZE; ++col)    //for each column (horizontally)
        {
            if ((row == cat_.getY) && (col == cat_.getX))
            {
                os << cat_.getSymbol(); //show cat
            }
            else
                if ((row == mouse_.getY()) && (col == mouse_.getX()))
                    os << mouse_.getSymbol();   //show mouse
                else
                {
                    bool holePresent(underground_.findHole(col, row));
                    if (holePresent == true) // If there is a hole at that location
                    {
                        os << HOLE; // Show hole symbol
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if ((row == nut_.getY()) && (col == nut_.getX()))
                        {
                            os << nut_.getSymbol(); //show mouse
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            os << FREECELL;//show free grid cell
                        }
                    }   
                }
        } //end of col-loop
        os << endl;
    } //end of row-loop
    return os.str();
} //end prepareGrid
```

The error is specifically the following:
Cat::getY': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Comment: You forgot the parentheses.  `if ((row == cat_.getY) && (col == cat_.getX))` => `if ((row == cat_.getY()) && (col == cat_.getX()))`  Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't want a pointer to member.  You just forgot the parentheses on your function call.

```
            if ((row == cat_.getY()) && (col == cat_.getX()))
```

Comment: I cant believe i didnt see that, thanks haha.

Answer (score 0):

assuming getY/getX are methods of cat_ and not poorly named public variables,
this

```
if ((row == cat_.getY) && (col == cat_.getX))
```

should be

```
if ((row == cat_.getY()) && (col == cat_.getX()))
```